# Mapply with do.call for multiple graphs

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I'm trying to use mapply to create a number of plots. I need input from list coordList to label each graph so I had to switch from lapply.

```
plotList<-mapply(function(listPart,rangeName)
                    {

                            resultsul<-unlist(results)
                                gName<-names(results[1])

                                ggplot(listPart, aes(x = factor(Var2), y=value)) + geom_violin()+
                                ggtitle(gName)+xlab(rangeName)+ylab("Coverage")+
                                stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "point", position = position_dodge(width = .9),
                                size = 6, shape = 4, show_guide = F)
                    }, listPart=results,rangeName=coordList)
do.call(grid.arrange, c(plotList, ncol=colnum))
```

unfortunately mapply doesnt seem to get along as well with do.call as lapply. I get the error

```
Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
input must be grobs!
```

anyway to fix this? Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the dput for results

```
structure(list(uc001aaa.3 = structure(list(Var1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Var2 = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L), value = c(878.186968838527, 
0, 1473.06397306397, 0, 0, 858.585858585859, 0, 0, 858.585858585859, 
0, 0, 286.195286195286, 0, 0, 732.323232323232, 0, 0, 1001.6835016835, 
0, 0, 538.720538720539, 0, 0, 3417.50841750842, 0, 0, 656.565656565657, 
0, 0, 622.895622895623)), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame"), uc001aal.1 = structure(list(Var1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Var2 = 1:10, value =c(98.1461286804798, 
370.774263904035, 229.007633587786, 556.161395856052, 719.738276990185, 
468.920392584515, 970.556161395856, 828.789531079607, 577.971646673937, 
1461.28680479826)), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("uc001aaa.3", "uc001aal.1"
))
```

Here is the dput for coordList

```
c("chr1 11874 14409", "chr1 69091 70008")
```

Here is what results looks like before it is fed into the mapply code (each $ is a small abridged portion)

```
$uc001aaa.3
   Var1 Var2     value
1     1    1  878.1870
2     2    1    0.0000
3     3    1 1473.0640
4     1    2    0.0000



$uc001aal.1
   Var1 Var2      value
1     1    1   98.14613
2     1    2  370.77426
3     1    3  229.00763
```

Here is another strategy I tried of using a loop to print out all the plots, still gives me the grobs error.

```
plotList<-list()

for (i in 1:length(results))
                    {
resultsul<-unlist(results)
gName<-names(resultsul[i])



#trying to plot multiple plots on one figure
plotList[i]<-ggplot(results[[i]], aes(x = factor(Var2), y=value)) + geom_violin()+ggtitle("gName")+xlab(coordList[i])+ylab("Coverage")+
stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "point", position = position_dodge(width = .9), size = 6, shape = 4, show_guide = F)


}
do.call(grid.arrange, c(list(plotList), ncol=colnum))
```

Comment: There is no way to run your code and identify the problem without having the `coordList` and `results` objects. Please use `dput` and add the output to the question. Furthermore, your past reluctance to accept or even upvote answers makes you come across as quite unappreciative of other peoples efforts to help you.

Comment: Hi, sorry I only recently discovered I could upvote or accept answers and some of the past few questions weren't upvoted for a variety of reasons, ie answered as a comment or not really solved. I didn't really appreciate how much more important upvoting is here than most other places so I'll try harder next time.

Comment: Well, I don't think you should upvote answers out of plain courtesy, but if you found them helpful I think you should do it even if they don't solve all the aspects of your problem.